# Select 2 library click move to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

When I click on the select2 container and when it will open my page has been scroll to top suddenly.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please share a snippet or demo, share your code

Comment: Are you / do you need to set the `dropdownParent` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is running in some bootstrap versions and select2.js . now I solved this problem by removing top prop in select2.js source .
- Open select2.js or select2.min.js
- Find $dropdownContainer.remove() and then you can see top property . remove it and then save the file.

You can see the problem for another persons :
https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/fL9fj2sL/1

```
Thankyou
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
.select2-container, .select2-dropdown, .select2-search, .select2-results {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

I hope this helps someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

Setting select2's dropdownParent solved this for me. Just set the dropdownParent property to its parent element like below:

```
$('select[data-plugin="select2"]').select2({
   dropdownParent: $("#selectParent")
});
```

According to [documentation](https://select2.org/dropdown#dropdown-placement), it's default container is the body tag. So if not specified it focuses its parent when dismissed which ends up on top of the page. dropdownParent is also needed while using select2 in a bootstrap modal.